# How to remove sticky class once div returns to its original point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I've got two navbars, the second becomes sticky once it hits the top of the viewport, the problem I'm having is getting it to 'unstick' when the div above which contains the original navbar comes back into the viewport so the first navbar can be seen again .

Sorry for the terrible explanation and vague title, had trouble trying to thing of how to describe it.

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjs527/ke8axcbw/5/) which will give you a much better idea of what I mean, any help would be appreciate as I'm pretty poor when it comes to javascript, thanks.

(HTML and CSS in jfiddle)

`````
  $('#nav2').attr("attop", false);
  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    var windowScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();


    if (windowScrollTop > lastScrollTop) {
      var header = $('#nav2[attop="false"]:first');
      if (header && header.length > 0) {
        if (windowScrollTop >= header.offset().top) {
          header.attr('attop', true);
          $('#nav2').addClass('sticky');
        }
      }

    }

    lastScrollTop = windowScrollTop;

  });
});
````
`````

Comment: Do you want to have 2 sticky navbars, second nav directly below first one?

Comment: @JakubMuda just want to have the 2nd navbar sticky, then have the 2nd navbar stop being sticky once the div with the orange background which contains the first navbar comes back into the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice solution in Bootstrap 4 and I use it on a few sites. The only thing you need to do is to add this class to the navbar. Check out the snippet below.

Notice that in order for position sticky to work correctly this class can't be added to an element inside a container, you must add this class to the container itself.

```css
@supports ((position: -webkit-sticky) or (position: sticky)) {
  .sticky-top {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1020;
  }
}

/*DEMO PURPOSE*/
nav{background:red;padding-top:1rem;padding-bottom:1rem}
.section-1{height:300px}
.section-2{height:1000px}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">Section 1</div>
<nav class="sticky-top">Lorem Ipsum</nav>
<div class="section-2">Section 1</div>
```

Comment: Solves the problem I was talking about, but I'm having trouble implementing it so its sticky for all the divs below, not just the first one.
[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jjs527/8Lxtgmb6/3/)

Comment: For pure CSS solution you need to make the nav `<ul id="nav2">` OUTSIDE of `<div id="ABOUT">`. Outherwise it will be sticky only to the end of container div. There is a JS workaround, but this is the easiest solution.

Comment: How stupid of me, thanks for point that out. All working great now!